# angular clean way of manipulating objects

Tags: angular, typescript

When I am creating or updating records I have a payload and with the dealTypeValues object , as you notice on the code the dealtype values differ between the type of dealDispositionType if it is buyout or sale , but my issue is the code is too long and seems not clean.

Does anyone has idea how to minimize the code so that I can minimize the payload or dealTtype values object declaration  ? or a way to cleanly implement the code below. As you can see there are lots of payloads objects. Thank you.

#html code

```
<ng-template #editButtons>
        <div class="flex" *ngIf="isEditing">
          <app-page-section-cards-btn
            [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.cancel"
            (btnClickEvent)="cancelEdit()"></app-page-section-cards-btn>
          <app-page-section-cards-btn
            [btnData]="pageSectionsOptions.btnData.save"
            (btnClickEvent)="saveDeal()">
        </app-page-section-cards-btn>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
```

#ts code

```
saveDeal(){
    if(!this.isExistingDeal){
      if(this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Buyout') {
        const dealTypeValues = {
          "id": 0,
          "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
          "summary": this.dealDispositionFormFields.summary,
          "terminationPayment": this.dealDispositionFormFields.terminationPayment,
          "effectiveDate": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealDispositionFormFields.effectiveDate),
          "totalBrokerCommission": this.dealDispositionFormFields.totalBrokerCommission,
          "dealId:": 0,
        } 

        const payload = {
          "id": 0,
          "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
          "dealType": "Idle Buyout",
          "annualRentProposed": null,
          "annualRentCurrent": null,
          "firmTermRemaining": null,
          "firmTermAdded": null,
          "maxAvailableTerm": null,
          "status": null,
          "capitalContribution": null,
          "parentCloneId": null,
          "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
          "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
          "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
        }

        this.createDispositionDeal(payload);
      }else if(this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Sale') {
        const dealTypeValues = {
          "id": 0,
          "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
          "salePrice": this.dealDispositionFormFields.salePrice,
          "brokerCommission": this.dealDispositionFormFields.brokerCommission,
          "transactionCosts": this.dealDispositionFormFields.transactionCosts,
          "earnestMoneyDeposit": this.dealDispositionFormFields.earnestMoneyDeposit,
          "inspectionPeriod": this.dealDispositionFormFields.inspectionPeriod,
          "estimatedClosingDate":  AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealDispositionFormFields.estimatedClosingDate),
          "netBookValue": this.dealDispositionFormFields.netBookValue,
          "dealId:": 0,
        } 

        const payload = {
          "id": 0,
          "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
          "dealType": "Idle Sale",
          "annualRentProposed": null,
          "annualRentCurrent": null,
          "firmTermRemaining": null,
          "firmTermAdded": null,
          "maxAvailableTerm": null,
          "status": null,
          "capitalContribution": null,
          "parentCloneId": null,
          "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
          "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
          "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
        }
        this.createDispositionDeal(payload);
      } 
    }else{
      if(this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Buyout') {
        const dealTypeValues = {
          "id": this.dealData.dealTypeValues.id,
          "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
          "summary": this.dealDispositionFormFields.summary,
          "terminationPayment": this.dealDispositionFormFields.terminationPayment,
          "effectiveDate": AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealDispositionFormFields.effectiveDate),
          "totalBrokerCommission": this.dealDispositionFormFields.totalBrokerCommission,
          "dealId": this.dealData.dealTypeValues.dealId,
        } 

        const payload = {
          "id": this.dealData.id,
          "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
          "dealType": "Idle Buyout",
          "annualRentProposed": null,
          "annualRentCurrent": null,
          "firmTermRemaining": null,
          "firmTermAdded": null,
          "maxAvailableTerm": null,
          "status": this.dealData.status,
          "capitalContribution": null,
          "parentCloneId": null,
          "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
          "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
          "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
        }
        this.updateDispositionDeal(payload);
      }else if (this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealDispositionType === 'Sale') {
        const dealTypeValues = {
          "id": this.dealData.dealTypeValues.id,
          "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
          "summary": this.dealDispositionFormFields.summary,
          "salePrice": this.dealDispositionFormFields.salePrice,
          "brokerCommission": this.dealDispositionFormFields.brokerCommission,
          "transactionCosts": this.dealDispositionFormFields.transactionCosts,
          "earnestMoneyDeposit": this.dealDispositionFormFields.earnestMoneyDeposit,
          "inspectionPeriod": this.dealDispositionFormFields.inspectionPeriod,
          "estimatedClosingDate":  AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(this.dealDispositionFormFields.estimatedClosingDate),
          "netBookValue": this.dealDispositionFormFields.netBookValue,
          "dealId": this.dealData.dealTypeValues.dealId,
        } 

        const payload = {
          "id": this.dealData.id,
          "name": this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
          "dealType": "Idle Sale",
          "annualRentProposed": null,
          "annualRentCurrent": null,
          "firmTermRemaining": null,
          "firmTermAdded": null,
          "maxAvailableTerm": null,
          "status": this.dealData.status,
          "capitalContribution": null,
          "parentCloneId": null,
          "accountId": this.currentAccount.accountId,
          "transactionId": this.transactionData.id,
          "dealTypeValues": JSON.stringify(dealTypeValues)
        }
        this.updateDispositionDeal(payload);
      }
    }
    
   }
    createDispositionDeal(payload:any) {
      this._dealService.createDeal(payload)
      .subscribe(
        res=>{
          this._notificationService.showSuccess('Deal was successfully created.');
          this.gotoManageDealsEvent.emit('');
        },
        err=>{
          console.log('Error creating deal')
        }
      )
    }
    updateDispositionDeal(payload:any) {
      this._dealService.updateDeal(payload)
      .subscribe(
        res=>{
          this._notificationService.showSuccess('Deal was successfully updated.');
          this.gotoManageDealsEvent.emit('');
        },
        err=>{
          console.log('Error creating deal')
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TypeScript [Object destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring) and [Spread](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest) Syntax

Create a modal for `DispositionalDeal`. Change property type as per your need.

```
export interface DispositionalDeal {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  dealType: string;
  annualRentProposed: number;
  annualRentCurrent: number;
  firmTermRemaining: number;
  firmTermAdded: number;
  maxAvailableTerm: number;
  status: string;
  capitalContribution: number;
  parentCloneId: number;
  accountId: number;
  transactionId: string;
  dealTypeValues: any;
}
```

Create getter for payload (Default values will be as per `Buyout` `createDispositionDeal` )

```
  get buyOutDealTypeValues(): any {
    const {
      dealName,
      summary,
      terminationPayment,
      effectiveDate,
      totalBrokerCommission,
    } = this.dealDispositionFormFields;
    return {
      id: 0,
      name: dealName,
      summary,
      terminationPayment,
      effectiveDate: AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(effectiveDate),
      totalBrokerCommission,
      dealId: 0,
    };
  }

  get payload(): DispositionalDeal {
    return {
      id: 0,
      name: this.dealDispositionFormFields.dealName,
      dealType: 'Idle Buyout',
      annualRentProposed: null,
      annualRentCurrent: null,
      firmTermRemaining: null,
      firmTermAdded: null,
      maxAvailableTerm: null,
      status: null,
      capitalContribution: null,
      parentCloneId: null,
      accountId: this.currentAccount.accountId,
      transactionId: this.transactionData.id,
      dealTypeValues: this.buyOutDealTypeValues,
    };
  }
```

Getter for Sales `DealTypeValues`

```
  get salesDealTypeValues(): any {
    const {
      dealName,
      salePrice,
      brokerCommission,
      transactionCosts,
      earnestMoneyDeposit,
      inspectionPeriod,
      estimatedClosingDate,
      netBookValue,
    } = this.dealDispositionFormFields;
    return {
      id: 0,
      name: dealName,
      salePrice,
      brokerCommission,
      transactionCosts,
      earnestMoneyDeposit,
      inspectionPeriod,
      estimatedClosingDate: AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(estimatedClosingDate),
      netBookValue,
      dealId: 0,
    };
  }
```

So `saveDeal()` will be as

```
  saveDeal() {
    const { dealDispositionType } = this.dealDispositionFormFields;

    let request = {};

    if (!this.isExistingDeal) {
      if (dealDispositionType === 'Buyout') {
        request = this.payload; // Since payload is as per Buyout creation no need to do any manipulation
      } else if (dealDispositionType === 'Sale') {
        request = {
          ...this.payload,
          dealTypeValues: this.salesDealTypeValues,
          dealType: 'Idle Sale',
        };
      }

      this.createDispositionDeal(JSON.stringify(request));
    } else {
      const { dealTypeValues, id, status } = this.dealData;
      if (dealDispositionType === 'Buyout') {
        const dealType = {
          ...this.buyOutDealTypeValues,
          id: dealTypeValues.id,
          dealId: dealTypeValues.dealId,
        };

        request = {
          ...this.payload,
          dealTypeValues: dealType,
          id,
          status,
        };
      } else if (dealDispositionType === 'Sale') {
        const dealType = {
          ...this.salesDealTypeValues,
          id: dealTypeValues.id,
          dealId: dealTypeValues.dealId,
          summary: this.dealDispositionFormFields.summary,
        };

        request = {
          ...this.payload,
          dealTypeValues: dealType,
          dealType: 'Idle Sale',
          id,
          status,
        };
      }

      this.updateDispositionDeal(JSON.stringify(request));
    }
  }
```

Let me know if you did not understand anything.

[Full Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qtwfml?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Sir , thanks for this one. I have another question which is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312773/converting-excel-formula-to-javascript-code , maybe you have an idea with this. Thanks